# find command cygwin problems

Tags: regex, bash, shell, find

I"m having a problem with the "find" command on cgywin. I have a test file here found with this command:

```
$ find . 'test'
.
./asdftest
./asdftext.txt
./test
./test/asdfastest.txt
./test/test.txt
./test.txt
./textasfa.txt
test
test/asdfastest.txt
test/test.txt
```

I am completely baffled as to why when I do

```
find . -regex 'test'
```

I get nothing as the result. I have tried many many combinations and never any luck. Whats going on? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `-name` option:

```
 find . -name '*test*'
```

With the `-regex`option, following will work since each filename will start with `./`:

```
find . -regex './.*test.*'
```

OR more accurate:

```
find . -regex '^\./.*test.*'
```

Comment: Since that will exactly match a file names `test` however you have filenames such as `test.txt`

Comment: I never realized that terminal used a file matching pattern that is different from the normal regular expression pattern. A quick google search enlightened me. Thanks once again.